why can promise have only resolve
I can define as below
new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Promise Done');
      }, 2000);
    });

But according to the below promise.d.ts file, both resolve and reject are needed, right?
interface PromiseConstructor

new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;


It's not necessary to declare all the arguments; in fact you don't need to declare any of them.

That’s the beauty of JavaScript. See The Arguments Object.

JavaScript initialises all named parameters to undefined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#default_parameters

It's unclear if the OP's problem is with JS or TS, as the answer would be different. Any way, the result is the same, the params are optional, added TS-specific dupe
